# How to insert long type data in to SQL SERVER Big int type

Tags: c#, sql-server

HI recently im working on a project . Its easy for INT but due to overflow situation I want to use bigInt in sql column and i'm sending him a LONG type data like  `Long l="Somthing value"`
and inserting like `Insert into Table value(Given Value)`

But why there is an error saying "Given value is not matching with the table definition "

Give me a sample code if possible

Comment: What about instead of us giving you sample code, you post the one that does not work? Because the sample likely works but you will use it wrong like you do the current one. And use parameters please.

Answer (score 0):

Specify column names when inserting.

```
into Table(Give_Value_Column) Values(Given Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are inserting correct values in table. Suppose you have three column and you are inserting four values then error will occur.

suppose you have following column
i.e. column1, column2 column3 etc. and you insert statement

`insert into tablename(column1, column2, column3) values ('somevalue','somevalue','somevalue')`

Here value is based on datatype that you have mentioned while creating a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
command = Insert into Table value(Given=@Value)
command.perameter.add(@value, datatype, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention the column name in the insert statement, what ever the columns are you going to insert

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for things that aren't code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field in the table is of type bigint, it is not possible to store a long value there. You could change your application to use an integer for the value, or you can cast the long to an int64 (eq to a bigint in sql) this will drop all the decimal values of the long.